# How to identify the isoceles triangles in a grid of 0's and 1's?

Tags: python, arrays

Consider a grid of say 10 * 10 size consisting of random 0 's and 1's. I want to identify the highest level isoceles triangle in the grid

Grid:

```
1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1

1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1

1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0

1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
```

Expected output:

Highest level of the triangle is 3

Comment: find the triangle only up direction, or including four directions?

Comment: what you have been tried so far ? We are not here to solve your homeworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume only find triangle up-direction, with all `1` or all `0`. such as:

```
    1         
  1 1 1       0 
1 1 1 1 1   0 0 0
```

you can start from the top point and find the max triangle by `backtracking`, which I implement in `find_max_triangle`, and then traverse all the matrix, and start from every point of it.

we can decrease traversal time by skiping some points. The optimization is pruning i, j by current max_level:

```
def max_triangles(matrix):
    m, n = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    max_level = 1

    def find_max_triangle(x, y, v):
        nonlocal max_level
        cur_level = 1
        while True:
            x += 1
            if x == m:
                return
            for i in range(-cur_level, cur_level + 1):
                _y = y + i
                if _y < 0 or _y >= n or matrix[x][_y] != v:
                    return
            cur_level += 1
            max_level = max(max_level, cur_level)

    for i in range(m):
        # optimization: pruning i by current max_level
        if i + max_level >= m:
            break
        for j in range(n):
            # optimization: pruning j by current max_level
            if j - max_level >= 0 and j + max_level < n:
                find_max_triangle(i, j, matrix[i][j])

    return max_level
```

test and output:

```
matrix = [[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
          [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]

print(max_triangles(matrix))

# output 3
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )